# Background of Div with list doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I need help on adding a background on my DIV. But I can't make it work.

Please refer on http://jsfiddle.net/NGyWu/8/

I created one DIV with black background. Inside a DIV is a paragraph and `list`

Problem: Only the paragraph has black background. The list doesn't have. I want the black background of the entire DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the float in the UL and the relative position you have assigned to the UL inside it.

Add `position: absolute` to `#topbar` and it will render as you intended.

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow:auto;` to `#topbar`.

Check: http://jsfiddle.net/NGyWu/12/

Alternatively you can use [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NGyWu/11/

What I did is:

1. Removed `float:left` from the `<ul>`
2. Made `<li>` to display as `inline-block`;

Answer (score 0):

Your `<ul>` element is floating.  That float needs to be cleared.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>                  
</ul>
<br style='clear:both'>
```

will solve your problem ([updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGyWu/16/)).

Answer (score 0):

Your `<ul>` is floated to the left, you need to clear your float.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/NGyWu/17/

```
<div id="topbar">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vel quam vehicula, congue orci et, pulvinar dolor.</p>    

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>                  
    </ul>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```